# nbandroid - how to launch debugger when program crashed?

Tags: java, android, debugging, netbeans

I just started using nbandroid plugin with Netbeans 7.0.1 (and 7.1). I could compile and set breakpoint to debug my program.

However, there is one feature in Eclipse I can't seem to figure out in Netbeans, which is to attach debugger when program crash. In Eclipse, I can break an android program at anytime, and it will open debug window with local variable info as well as call stack. This is true for the program crashed too. Eclipse will point at line which cause error with the input parameter values. However, in Netbeans, I can only track these information in LogCat and I cannot open source code debugger.

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Services tab (Ctrl-5) and you can see attached devices and connect with debugger to running processes. Connecting to a crashed process is not supported though. I am not sure what should be the result.

Of course I you want to see more features consider some donation at http://www.nbandroid.org/

-Radim